# Importing a default namespace - why am I getting "undefined"?

Tags: typescript, cocoscreator

I try to learn typescript - make some first steps :). Here's my problem.

I created **File1.ts** as follows:

```
export namespace ex {
    export var mapper = ( ob : Object ) : NewClass {
        return ob as NewClass;
    };

    export class NewClass extends Object {
        public getSomething() : number {
            return 2;
        }
    };
}
```

Then, I created **File2.ts**, which uses the "mapper" defined in first file:

```
import { ex } from './Ex';

var a : Object = myAlreadyExistingObject;
console.log( ex.mapper( a ).getSomething() );
```

---

What I get:

**ERROR: TypeError: File1_1.ex.mapper(a).getSomething is not a function.**

The "Object" class is just an example - in reality I'm using an already defined, complex class. What I'm trying to achieve is to have "extension methods" like in C#, using it like this: `ex.mapper( instance ).newFunction()`

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Forgot to add - the error says it's **"not a function, but undefined"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return ob as NewClass;
```

Type assertions in TypeScript **don't cause runtime changes**. If `ob` didn't have a `getSomething` method before, then the return value of this function won't either, and you'll get the error described.